# Wordpress Meta Box plugin, retrieving image url from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

Having a bit of bother with the Wordpress Meta Box plugin, specifically with retrieving an image url from an image added to a custom post type.

I'm creating meta boxes in a custom plugin, like so:

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'xxx_meta_register_meta_boxes' );

    function xxx_meta_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes )
    {

    $prefix = 'xxx_meta_';

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
    'title' => esc_html__( 'Retailer Information', '' ),
    'id'         => 'advanced',
    'post_types' => array( 'xxx_retailers' ),
    'autosave'   => true,
    'fields'     => array(

      // PLUPLOAD IMAGE UPLOAD (WP 3.3+)
            array(
                'name'             => esc_html__( 'Retailer Logo', '' ),
                'id'               => "{$prefix}plupload",
                'type'             => 'plupload_image',
                'max_file_uploads' => 1,
            ),

            // URL
            array(
                'name' => esc_html__( 'Link', '' ),
                'id'   => "{$prefix}url",
                'desc' => esc_html__( 'Clicking the retailer logo will take the user to this URL', '' ),
                'type' => 'url',
                'std'  => 'xxx',
            ),
        )
    );
    return $meta_boxes;
    }
```

So far so good, these boxes are relevant to a custom post type 'xxx_retailers'.

The problem comes with retrieving this data. I want to display my retailers in a widget. I've chopped and changed another piece of code I've used previously, but it's not returning the image URL, just the ID. Unfortunately I don't know enough php to figure out why.

```
// Create Retailers Widget
    // Create the widget
    class Retailers_Widget extends WP_Widget {
        function __construct() {
                parent::__construct(
                        // base ID of the widget
                        'retailers_widget',
                        // name of the widget
                        __('XXX Retailers List', '' ),
                        // widget options
                        array (
                            'description' => __( 'Shows a list of retailer logos', '' )
                        )
                    );
    }
        function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            // kick things off
            extract( $args );
            echo $before_widget;
            echo $before_title . 'Retailers' . $after_title;

      // Pull through Retailers
      $xxxretailers = get_posts(array(
                        'post_type' => 'xxx_retailers',
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'asc',
                    ));

    // Display for each Retailer
    foreach ($xxxretailers as $xxxretailer) {
      $custom = get_post_custom($xxxretailer->ID);
      $meta_ret_img = $custom["xxx_meta_plupload"][0];
      $meta_ret_url = $custom["xxx_meta_url"][0];
      // Display Retailers
      echo "<li><a href='{$meta_ret_url}'><img src='{$meta_ret_img}' /></a></li>";
           }
        }
};
// Register widget
function register_retailers_widget() {
  register_widget( 'Retailers_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_retailers_widget' );
```

The URLs are coming through correctly, so I know this is a problem with the line

```
$meta_ret_img = $custom["xxx_meta_plupload"][0];
```

But I can't figure out how to get the image URL from the data I presume is stored as an array. Any ideas?

Edit:

I should have mentioned, in a single post I can get a single image with:

```
$images = rwmb_meta( 'xxx_meta_plupload', 'size=medium' );
if ( !empty( $images ) ) {
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        echo "<img src='{$image['url']}' />";
    }
}
```

But I want to show images from all my retailers post types, to create a list of logos.

Comment: can you add the output of `var_dump($custom);` here

Comment: Sure, out comes the following:

array(6) { ["_edit_lock"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "1472408521:1" } ["_edit_last"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" } ["_revision-control"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "a:1:{i:0;s:8:"defaults";}" } ["_yoast_wpseo_content_score"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "30" } ["xxx_meta_url"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(163) "[Redacted]" } ["xxx_meta_plupload"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "1862" } }

Comment: also i would like to know why you use curly braces in `src` attribute of `img` tag, please also add output of following statement `echo $custom["xxx_meta_url"][0];`

Comment: Curly brackets, no particular reason other than they were in the code example I first followed. As I said, I don't know a lot of php so this is kind of pieced together from tutorials.

$custom["xxx_meta_url"] outputs the url entered in the url metabox in my first code example above. This comes out just as it's entered.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it's just the same. The href url is coming through, but the url for the img src isn't. I'm just getting the image id, which is a 4 digit number. It's not that the code doesn't work, it's that I can't figure out to get what I want, which is the image url, not the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this statement:

```
$meta_ret_img = $custom["xxx_meta_plupload"][0];
```

with this:

```
$meta_ret_img_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom["xxx_meta_plupload"][0]);

$meta_ret_img = $meta_ret_img_array[0];
```

also please remove all these curly braces from `src` and `href` attributes from your code.

if you are interested in any particular size of the image, then see the official document of `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` function [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/).

For e.g. for **medium** size image you can write it as:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src($custom["xxx_meta_plupload"][0], 'medium');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately the img src is showing as `<img src="Array">`, still not getting that url.

Comment: Ah that works! Thank you Tarun! I'm very grateful for your help. In a display of bare faced cheek I don't suppose you know how to change the image size here? It's displaying the thumbnail but I need the medium sized image.

Comment: also if you need any particular size of the image, like thumbnail , medium, large, you can use size parameter of this function, see the official documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/).

Comment: This is excellent, makes perfect sense. Such a big help, thank you!